# Finish all activities in Basic4Android

Tags: basic4android

I have an application with many activities, sharing the same Menu, which is created in a code module. This Menu has an option "Exit". How do I finish all running activities without using ExitApplication? Do I have to create a variable in the code module (ExitNow as boolean) and check it in every Activity_Resume of every activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put activity.finish as the code for your exit button

Comment: You could add a flag as a single

Comment: on finish you could have flag=flag+1 and check the value of flag on resumsion also changing flag back to 0  at that time.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

type this in prossec global :

```
Dim GExit as boolean

Gexit= false
```

type in all resume in all activity this code:

```
if Gexit = true then activity.finish
```

and type this code in your BTNEXIT:

```
Gexit= true

activity.finish
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of examples but this really worked for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```